# .Net 7.0 Blazor Server razor component onclick not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor, blazor-server-side

I am implementing a razor component into my blazor server app and am not able to get my onclick functions to work.

Many Solutions involve adding `<base href="~/" />` or `<script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>`

Neither of these have worked but I noticed that chrome devtools does not show a blazor.server.js?

`Container.razor`

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web;

<button class="Container" @onclick="Select">
    <img class="SongImage" src="data:image/png;base64,@PartyPanelUI.GlobalData.covers[level.LevelId]" />
    <div class="SongTextContainer">
        <p class="ListTitle" align="left">@level.Name</p>
        <p class="AuthorMapper" align="left">
            @level.Author @if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(@level.Mapper))
            {
                <span style="font-size: 15pt;">[<span style="color: cadetblue">@level.Mapper</span>]</span>
            }
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="SongMetaContainer">
        <p class="SubMetadata" align="right">@level.Duration</p>
        <p class="SubMetadata" align="right">@level.BPM</p>
    </div>
</button>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public PartyPanelShared.Models.PreviewBeatmapLevel level { get; set; }
    public void Select()
    {
        PartyPanelShared.Logger.Error("wadf");
        PartyPanelUI.Pages.IndexModel.Select(level);
    }
}
```

`<component type="typeof(PartyPanelUI.Components.Container)" param-level="@lvl" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />`

Here is my PreviewBeatmapLevel class that uses Protobuf

```
using ProtoBuf;
using System;

namespace PartyPanelShared.Models
{
    [ProtoContract]
    public class Characteristic
    {
        public Characteristic(string name, string[] diffs)
        {
            Name = name;
            this.diffs = diffs;
        }

        [ProtoMember(1)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [ProtoMember(2)]
        public string[] diffs { get; set; }

    }

    [ProtoContract]
    public class PreviewBeatmapLevel
    {
        [ProtoMember(1)]
        public string LevelId { get; set; }
        [ProtoMember(2)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [ProtoMember(3)]
        public string SubName { get; set; }
        [ProtoMember(4)]
        public string Author { get; set; }
        [ProtoMember(5)]
        public string Mapper { get; set; }
        [ProtoMember(6)]
        public string Duration { get; set; }
        [ProtoMember(7)]
        public float BPM { get; set; }
        [ProtoMember(8)]
        public byte[] cover { get; set; } //Cover Imaage stored as bytes
        [ProtoMember(9)]
        public string coverPath { get; set; }
        [ProtoMember(10)]
        public bool Favorited { get; set; }
        [ProtoMember(12)]
        public bool Owned { get; set; }
        [ProtoMember(13)]
        public Characteristic[] chars { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The template I used is ASP.NET Core Web App.

Comment: Could you share your PreviewBeatmapLevel  model?

Comment: What is the template of Visual Studio you used to create your project?

Comment: @QingGuo Here is my PreviewBeatmapLevel class, it uses protobuf

Comment: @QingGuo Is there anymore info that you need?

Comment: I don't know  what's your  "PartyPanelShared.Logger.Error("wadf");
        PartyPanelUI.Pages.IndexModel.Select(level);" in your Select() . You can try "private int currentCount = 0;
    public void Select()
    {        
        currentCount++;
    }"  and "<p role="status">Current count: @currentCount</p>" to see  if onclick  firing or not.

Comment: " chrome devtools does not show a blazor.server.js" You can see the sources tab to see if _framwork has show a`blazor.server.js`  like : https://i.stack.imgur.com/UR4Vz.gif

Comment: @QingGuo I did check sources under _framework.

Comment: Do you have `<script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>` in your _Host.cshtml?

Comment: @QingGuo yes I do